# how users interact with deployed smart contract in ethereum wallet/Mist browser?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, mist, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp

What is the next step after contract  deployment in ethereum wallet?

i have implemented crypto currency using this tutorial.
[link to tutorial](https://ethereum.org/token)

and successfully deployed.

How this contract will use outside Mist browser or other people? Like in browser or need to develop like app by using other tools? . Please suggest? I am very new to this block chain.